# Vue Google Maps Undefined - Single Marker Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to map one location on a `Google Map` in `Vue 2` using `Vue-google-maps-2`. I am using code that should work, as I am using it for calls in other parts of my app to plot multiple markers from an array. The error is making no sense as I am only reusing code that works elsewhere. The error is as follows:

> ""TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined"

I have tried to add `Number()` and `parseFloat()` onto the inputs into the `window.google.maps.LatLng()` section (which is where the error is residing as far as I can see. Code below (I have excluded the `CSS`), any help greatly appreciated for such a noob error.

UPDATE: I think the offending code is

```
new window.google.maps.LatLng
```

I think this is firing before Google Maps has loaded. Any advice?

```
<div class="col-12">
  <GmapMap
    :center="center"
    :zoom="zoom"
    map-type-id="terrain"
    ref="map"
  >         
    <GmapMarker
      :position="propertyLocation"
      :clickable="false"
    />
  </GmapMap>
</div>

<script>
import { gmapApi } from "vue2-google-maps";

export default {
  name: 'BlogPost',
  data() {
    return {
      propid: "",
      location: [{ "id": 2, "name": "Chatterbridge", "lat": 52.2679288, "lng": -1.1202549, "postcode": "NN11", "country": "GB", "bedrooms": "1", "price": "65000" }]
      center: {
        lat: 52.2046,
        lng: -1.77,
      },
      zoom: 12,
    };
  },
 
  created() {
    this.propid = Number(this.$route.params.slug)
    this.location = locations.find(locations => locations.id === this.propid)
    this.propertyLocation = new window.google.maps.LatLng(this.location.lat, this.location.lng);
  }, 

  computed: {
    google: gmapApi,
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: `google` doesn't exist on `window`. What do you get when you console log `window`?

Comment: The Window element is required for using the vue plugin for Google Maps, all the other Google code uses this structure. It took me ages to get maps up and running in Vue until I found maps needed this Window aspect.How would I console.log Window?

Comment: When the component's `created()` lifecycle hook is called, the Google Maps API probably has not finished loading yet: therefore `window.google` is undefined and so `window.google.maps` will throw an error. You will need to wait for the Google Maps API to be loaded before attempting to do it:

Comment: [`window` is a global object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp). All you need to do is `console.log(window)`

Comment: ok, I did that and I can see Google maps listed under Window. Which makes sense as the code works elsewhere albeit used for an array.

Answer (score 1):

From [these docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) (I'm guessing this is the package you're using). How you have `google` setup in `computed` means you can use `this` instead of `window`:

```
this.propertyLocation = new this.google.maps.LatLng(this.location.lat, this.location.lng);
```

Comment: I have tried this but I get the same error. This: this.propertyLocation = new window.google.maps.LatLng(this.location.lat, this.location.lng); is definitely the offending line. I don't understand why this would cause an issue.

Comment: Yeah, just tried it and still no luck.I have attached that function to a method and fired it on a button. The code works. I think that the code is executing before Google maps has time to load. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 100)` to fix it but I've no idea why you'd need to do this

Comment: Cheer Dan, I think I must have an issue with my app structure or something silly in the code. Its a tiny app so it should be fine, especially as I am doing nothing taxing. Thanks for your help, I am going to have to rebuild from the ground up as I cant post the whole app on here for people to debug. Cheers